# Adding item to array PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm building a shopping cart for a school assignment. I'm pretty much there except for adding the items to the cart variable.

I've set up my cart session with: `$_SESSION['temp_session'] = array();`

and then, when a item is added to the cart, this code is executed

```
if (isset($_POST['addtocart'])) {
            $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            $qty = $_POST['qty'];

            $newItem = $item_name.":".$price.":".$qty;
            //echo $newItem;

            if (isset($_SESSION['shop_session'])) {
                array_push($shop_session, $newItem);
                //header('Location: cart.php');
                print_r($shop_session);
            }
            else {
                array_push($temp_session, $newItem);
                //header('Location: login.php?notLoggedIn=true');
                print_r($temp_session);
            }
        }
```

it all seem s to be working fine (i can print out `$newItem`  and it contains the elements) but when I try to add `$newItem` to either `$shop_session` or `$temp_session` and then print them out, there array is empty.

Is this something to do with the way I'm using `array_push()` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your [RegisterGlobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) is on? If not you must use

```
            if (isset($_SESSION['shop_session'])) {
                    array_push($_SESSION['shop_session'], $newItem);
                    //header('Location: cart.php');
                    print_r($_SESSION);
            }
            else {
                array_push($_SESSION['temp_session'], $newItem);
                    //header('Location: login.php?notLoggedIn=true');
                    print_r($_SESSION);
            }
```

Comment: @Anax If you don't know how that relates to `register_globals` then you've never come across a script that has been coded with it on.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks guys. with the print_r($_SESSION); i'm getting: Array ( [temp_session] => Array ( [0] => Apocalypso:10.00:2 ) ). So $_SESSION is an array, and within it is another array called temp_session? how would I copy temp_sessions to shop_session? and also, I guess a foreach($_SESSION['shop_session'] as $item) isn't going to work either?

Comment: @e.c.ho My initial impression was that Alexey was implying that with register_globals On, every session variable is automatically available as standalone variable as well, which I believe is not true.

Answer (score 3):

You can't type

```
$_SESSION['temp_session'] = array();
```

and expect to have a variable named $temp_session. All you have is an array ($_SESSION) which contains an element (with key name `temp_session`), which in turn is an array as well.

In order to have the desired results you need an additional line, such as:

```
$temp_session = $_SESSION['temp_session'];
```

and when you update that, back again into your session:

```
$_SESSION['temp_session'] = $temp_session;
```